# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I use **epub-gen** in `reactjs`.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.existsSync is not a function

I tested `import * as fs from "fs"`   instead of  `var fs = require("fs")`.

epub-gen/lib/index.js [here](https://github.com/cyrilis/epub-gen/blob/master/lib/index.js).

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 2.3.2
(function() {
  var fs = require("fs");
...
  EPub = class EPub {
..
      if (!fs.existsSync(this.options.tempDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(this.options.tempDir);
      }
    ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to generate file using web application. It's impossible to use FileSystem inside react web application because browser doesn't have access to file system.

To do that you should create backend in `node` and use this piece of code in your node application.

Comment: So I can not use epub-gen this way?

Comment: That’s right, as I can see ePub-gen needs access to file system which can be only achieved using node to run JavaScript file